# Comparing laws, regulations, and rules

Tags: meaning

As I understand it, laws are made to protect property, regulations are made to control our behavior (both are made by governments), but rules are made by individuals or organizations. Please explain these.

Answer (score 1):

In many societies the government's legislative branch makes the laws, and the executive branch creates the regulations implementing the law.

For example, in California the State legislature (through a popular referendum) passed a **law** permitting the use of medicinal marijuana, but the **regulations** regarding how much marijuana patients could possess, what form any ID card should take, etc., were created by the Public Health Departments of each county.

As for **rules**, I would say that term is a superset that includes both laws and regulations.

Answer (score 0):

I would say rules and regulations are general terms for things an authority says people should or shouldn't do. Laws are more specific rules and regulations legislated by a government - the breaking of which could be a criminal matter.

**[rule](https://www.google.com/search?q=rule%20definition)**

> noun
>   1. one of a set of explicit or understood regulations or principles governing conduct or procedure within a particular area of activity.

(Google)

**[regulation](https://www.google.com/search?q=regulation%20definition)**

> noun
>   1. a rule or directive made and maintained by an authority.

(Google)

**[law](https://www.google.com/search?q=law%20definition)**

> noun
>   1. the system of rules which a particular country or community recognizes as regulating the actions of its members and which it may
>   enforce by the imposition of penalties.

(Google)

You'll see that Google defines rules and regulations as each other. Laws on the other hand are specific to countries or communities and includes the imposition of penalties.

---

PS: Laws aren't just about protecting property. Murder is usually a crime for example.